# PHP json_decode() with multi level key-value pairs from C#

Tags: c#, php, json

I am using multiple levels of JSON data coming into php from a C# application, as in:

```
return new RootObject()
{
ID_Project = 4,
Name_Project = "Test",
Receiver_ID = 4,
Receiver_Name = "ABCDE",
UserID = 20,
UserRole = new User_Role()
{
ID_User = 20,
Role_User = "level 3",
User_Role_Description = "U",
UserGroup = new List<user_group>()
{
new User_Group() { ID_UserGroup = 30, Name_UserGroup = "usergroup8", UserID = 20 },
new User_Group() { ID_UserGroup = 31, Name_UserGroup = "usergroup9", UserID = 21 },
new User_Group() { ID_UserGroup = 32, Name_UserGroup = "usergroup10", UserID = 22 }
}
}
};
```

i am having troubles accessing the second level: UserRole and 3rd level: User_Group in my php script.
im currently trying like this:

```
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
echo "<h2>$key</h2>";
foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

echo "$k | $v
";

foreach ($v as $key1) {

echo "$key1
";
}
}
}
```

new version in PHP: (after edit)

```
     //connect to the database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","userid","password","database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    };
    $jsonData = file_get_contents("JSON_File.json");
    $phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);

    $userRole = $phpArray->UserRole;
    $userGroups = $phpArray->UserRole->UserGroup;
    $id_project=$phpArray->ID_Project;
    $name_project=$phpArray->Name_Project;
$id_receiver=$phpArray->Receiver_ID;
$name_receiver=$phpArray->Receiver_Name;
$userid=$phpArray->UserID;
$id_user=$phpArray->UserRole->ID_User;
$role_user=$phpArray->UserRole->Role_User;
$role_user_description=$phpArray->UserRole->User_Role_Description;

    $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO project (`ID_Project`,`Name_Project`,`Receiver_ID`,`Receiver_Name`,`UserID`) VALUES ($id_project, '$name_project',$id_receiver,'$name_receiver',$userid);" ;


    $sqlStr.= "INSERT INTO user_role (`ID_User`,`UserRole`,`User_Role_Description`)  VALUES ($id_user,'$role_user','$role_user_description');" ;
    foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
    $id_usergroup=$userGroup->ID_UserGroup;
    $name_usergroup=$userGroup->Name_UserGroup . PHP_EOL;
    $userid=$userGroup->UserID . PHP_EOL;  

    $sqlStr.= "INSERT INTO user_group (`ID_UserGroup`,`Name_UserGroup`,`UserID`) VALUES ($id_usergroup, '$name_usergroup',$userid)" ;
    }
    if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $sqlStr)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            //check the outcome

        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($con)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
    }
```

**EDIT:** I have an issue with accessing the 3rd level data elements.
For Eg., I am able to get the values uptil Project-> Stand_Orte-> Modul. but after that Project-> Stand_Orte-> Modul-> MessKanal Throws an error in PHP as " Trying to get property of non-object  "

the JSON class structure from C# is as follows:

```
public class User_Group
    {
        public int ID_UserGroup { get; set; }
        public string Name_UserGroup { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
    }
    public class User_Role
    {
        public int ID_User { get; set; }
        public string Role_User { get; set; }
        public string User_Role_Description { get; set; }
        public List<User_Group> UserGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stand_Orte
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
        public List<Modul> modul { get; set; }
    }

    public class Modul
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Seriennummer { get; set; }
        public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
        public string StandortID { get; set; }
        public List<Mess_Kanal> MessKanal { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mess_Kanal
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string ModulID { get; set; }
        public List<LogMess_Daten> LogMessDaten { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogMess_Daten
    {
        public string KanalID { get; set; }
        public string Zeitstempel { get; set; }

    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        public int ID_Project { get; set; }
        public string Name_Project { get; set; }
        public int Receiver_ID { get; set; }
        public string Receiver_Name { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public User_Role UserRole { get; set; }
        public Stand_Orte Standorte { get; set; }
    }
```

does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
Revathy

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: And what do you put into $phpArray ?

Comment: @halcyon: {"ID_Project":4,"Name_Project":"Test","Receiver_ID":4,"Receiver_Name":"ABCDE","UserID":20,"UserRole":{"ID_User":20,"Role_User":"level 3","User_Role_Description":"U","UserGroup":[{"ID_UserGroup":30,"Name_UserGroup":"usergroup8","UserID":20},{"ID_UserGroup":31,"Name_UserGroup":"usergroup9","UserID":21},{"ID_UserGroup":32,"Name_UserGroup":"usergroup10","UserID":22}]}}

Comment: @RevathySanthanam You rang?

Comment: @RichardBernards: $jsonData = file_get_contents("JSON_superproject.json");
$phpArray = array(json_decode($jsonData, true));

Comment: Yeah :) I'm just getting the decoded JSON into $phpArray.

Comment: @RevathySanthanam not just decoded... you're putting it into an extra array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("JSON_superproject.json");
$json = json_decode($jsonData);

$userRole = $json->UserRole;
$userGroups = $json->UserRole->UserGroup;
```

So for example when trying to read the usergroups:

```
foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
    echo $userGroup->Name_UserGroup . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Since you are using everything as an object now, to load pieces which are between `{}`, you can get to them by using the `->` in PHP, pieces enclosed by `[]` are still arrays and what you are used to.

Examples:

```
echo $json->ID_Project;
echo $json->UserRole->ID_User;
```

Extra SQL information for the usergroups:
Replace your existing line with the sql statement to the following:

```
foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
    $sqlStr .= "INSERT INTO user_group (`ID_UserGroup`,`Name_UserGroup`,`UserID`) VALUES (" . $userGroup->ID_UserGroup . ", '" . $userGroup->Name_UserGroup . "', " . $userGroup->UserID . ");";
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try to use the UserRole object in my MYSQL query in PHP Script.  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$UserRole   Query: $sqlStr= "INSERT INTO user_role (`ID_User`,`UserRole`,`User_Role_Description`)  VALUES ($userRole->ID_User, '$userRole->UserRole',$userRole->User_Role_Description);" ;

Comment: Also, accessing of the first level became different now, since $json is no longer an array now... how could i access the 'RootObject' members, following the same footsteps mentioned above? to make use of these----- `code`ID_Project = 4,
Name_Project = "Test",
Receiver_ID = 4,
Receiver_Name = "ABCDE",
UserID = 20

Comment: See the extra examples in the answer to solve this. There is an explanation on how to use them as well.

Comment: it works for the first two levels, but when i use Insert on UserGroup, it spoils the others too... This is what I am doing...   `code` $jsonData = file_get_contents("JSON_superproject.json");
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
$userRole = $phpArray->UserRole;
$userGroups = $phpArray->UserRole->UserGroup;   
 *Continued Below*

Comment: $id_project=$phpArray->ID_Project;
$name_project=$phpArray->Name_Project;
$id_receiver=$phpArray->Receiver_ID;
$name_receiver=$phpArray->Receiver_Name;
$userid=$phpArray->UserID;
$id_user=$phpArray->UserRole->ID_User;
$role_user=$phpArray->UserRole->Role_User;
$role_user_description=$phpArray->UserRole->User_Role_Description;     *Continued Below*

Comment: $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO project (`ID_Project`,`Name_Project`,`Receiver_ID`,`Receiver_Name`,`UserID`) VALUES ($id_project, '$name_project',$id_receiver,'$name_receiver',$userid);" ;
 
 
 $sqlStr.= "INSERT INTO user_role (`ID_User`,`UserRole`,`User_Role_Description`)  VALUES ($id_user,'$role_user','$role_user_description');" ;      *Continued Below*

Comment: foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
$id_usergroup=$userGroup->ID_UserGroup;
$name_usergroup=$userGroup->Name_UserGroup . PHP_EOL;
$userid=$userGroup->UserID . PHP_EOL;  

 $sqlStr.= "INSERT INTO user_group (`ID_UserGroup`,`Name_UserGroup`,`UserID`) VALUES ($id_usergroup, '$name_usergroup',$userid)" ;
}

Comment: I do not see the Insert Values in the MYSQL database tables. could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong.. You can tell by my questions, that I'm super new to this. :(

Comment: Please add those comments in your original question... i would like to see some code formatting ;)

Comment: @RevathySanthanam I have ammended my answer with a possible solution. Code is not tested since I do not have all the information... But this looks like it should work

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work.. Then I tried to do the 'UserGroup' insert alone separately as a single query, and it still dint work.. @RichardBernards

Comment: print your sqlstring before sending it to the database, look in all your errorlogs, etc. without more information I am unable to help you further

Comment: Actually It seems to work now. Dont know how though.!!:-o SQL`code` string(518) "INSERT INTO project (`ID_Project`,`Name_Project`,`Receiver_ID`,`Receiver_Name`,`UserID`) VALUES (5, 'Test1',5,'ABCDEFGHI',21);INSERT INTO user_role (`ID_User`,`UserRole`,`User_Role_Description`) VALUES (21,'level 1, 3','R U');INSERT INTO user_group (`ID_UserGroup`,`Name_UserGroup`,`UserID`) VALUES (40, 'usergroup12', 23);INSERT INTO user_group (`ID_UserGroup`,`Name_UserGroup`,`UserID`) VALUES (41, 'usergroup13', 24);INSERT INTO user_group (`ID_UserGroup`,`Name_UserGroup`,`UserID`) VALUES (42, 'usergroup14', 25);"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, upto how many levels of data can we store into $json above; as in like, `code`$json->UserRole->ID_User->A->B->C->.............

Comment: The answer to that is not that simple... It depends on how slow your code can get until it is not according to spec anymore... The deeper nested (and the bigger the json gets), the harder it is to perform operations on it. In real life, most of the time you do not reach these limitations...

Comment: I see, But, I have big JSON structure and I am unable to go beyond level 2. As in here, `code`$json->UserRole->ID_User->A. when I try to access A#s elements I get error, 'Trying to get property of non-object'. Now, how i do that. please let me know the way around it.. :( @RichardBernards

Comment: It already tells you what is wrong... In your example, `ID_User` is not an object... probably it's an array or just a string or something. I cannot help you without the complete JSON, and this is beyond the scope of the original question in this thread

Comment: I have already edited my question above... with the full JSON structure and explanation of the issue.. and, i believe it is part of my original question.. :(

Comment: Its not part of your original question... And Modul is an array, not an object

Comment: yes, i agree. that is why i am using a for loop to get modul values.  but how do i go about accessing modul's messkanal's data? any ideas?

Comment: yes, i agree. that is why i am using a for loop to get modul values.  but how do i go about accessing modul's messkanal's data? any ideas?